Looking for advice for chronic mensturuation symptoms
I am writing this here as I lost hope in medical assistance after having doctors telling me "I don't know". I am 28 y.o years female and suffered from extra-pulmonary TB (tuberculosis) in the reproductive system and which got treated last year. I've had 6 surgeries mainly because doctors were unable to diagnose my sickness, but after the treatment finished my period got better (it was more painful before due to TB) but it is still a life blocking situation for me.
so basically this is how it goes, I feel severely exhausted and sleepy 15 days before my period with constant migraines with tension extending to the right side of my body all of it, feeling it numb and weak that I cannot hold a cup with my hand, not to mention that I can't follow a sleep schedule then my period starts and I can't do anything the best I can do is to get pain killers a warm blanket and sleep, after it ends I find myself in state of severe depression (to do it all over again) that I hate everything because literally my period is now an obstacle to the point it became a disability.
I went to several doctors, the gyno prescribed contraception pills (1 hormone) which didn't make my situation any better just gave me extra migraines, I went to a neurologist and all the scans show that I am "OK", I requested a general analysis for my body but the doctor refused claiming that my situation doesn't require this kind of intervention, I cannot live on pain killers forever as they are damaging my kidneys... All I know is that I am suffering, my body is in a chronic state of pain, the doctors don't seem to help, and the biggest one of all is my employer is barely understanding of my situation making me feel guilty about being sick every two months.
If anyone here had similar case or know a competent doctor that can offer a remote consultation or anything, please drop a comment.
My nutrition is all natural, vitamine levels are ok, blood analysis all ok, practice sport nearly everyday... I am already helpless that I am seeking help for such problem online .. I know, but this can give you an idea how much I can no longer bear with this situation.
Thank you in advance.

Hi hayax - this is something that absolutely can not be diagnosed or assisted through online groups or sites such as this. You need to consult qualified professionals. If the ones you have seen have not helped, you'll need to find others.
